# Programmatically adding/removing backends to/from Varnish-cache 4.x

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have a simple program for adding and removing backends for varnish 3.x. 
It's done in a simple way: there is a python program that accepts HTTP requests for adding and removing backends for named services. It adds and removes backends for specific directors using VCL configuration and then reloads config for varnish.

Now I wonder how to implement such a scheme for new (4.x) Varnish-cache. I see from documentation [directors have moved from VCL](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading.html#directors-have-been-moved-to-the-vmod-directors) modules to VMOD loadables. As I see it, now it's impossible to add new backend or director on-fly without restarting the whole varnish. Or am I wrong?

So the questions are:

1. Does Varnish-cache 4.x have any external [to varnish itself] API for managing configurations and directors in particular?
2. What's the best way to manage directors in Varnish 4.x in automatic way without varnish restart?

Answer (score 2):

Moving directors to VMODs is a step on the way to make the API service you ask about it #1.

Your software that writes VCL and loads it on changes can continue to operate as before. It is just the notation/syntax that have changed in 4.0. Use vcl.load / vcl.discard with varnishadm as usual to do #2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the new features with directors in VMOD is just an additional one, not replacing the old mode, did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Did you find a a solution to this @OlegBorisenko? It seems you cannot load individual backends (behind a director) with V4, at least I don't know where to get the director variable from.

Comment: @yawn no, I didn't try yet (according to plan, I'll do it in april)

Comment: I tested a bunch of stuff and simply reloading the while (boot) VCL works ok. I would be really awesome if we could get a `remove_backend` complement for directors though. This would make it easier to add and remove backends on the fly w/o generating VCL.

Comment: @yawn we're looking into this under the "dynamic backends" concept. it is fairly complex to do, so it takes a bit of time to get it right. I don't think it will make it into 4.1, but should be in master sometime this year.